# Getting EOFError when sending mail using ActionMailer in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, gmail, actionmailer

I've been trying to send emails using Rails' ActionMailer in production. It works fine in development, but I get `EOFError` when I try in production. The logs aren't very helpful to me, so could someone point me in the right direction on how to debug this? Or if you have encountered this before, how did you solve it?

This is my production config:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
  port:                 465,
  user_name:            ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
  password:             ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"],
  authentication:       :login,
  enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

Except for the username and password, it's exactly the same as my development config. Although if I use the prod credentials on development it still works. I am using port 465 since this is the one the I am able to successfully use for telnet (I can't connect to the google smtp server with 587 via telnet).

Here are the logs I get when I try to send an email:

```
[#15945]  INFO -- : [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [ae94a390-be07-4bdf-9fc5-dc7a58dd36ef] Performing ActionMailer::DeliveryJob from Inline(mailers) with arguments: "IndexMailer", "send_reset_password_email", "deliver_now!", gid://api/User::Student/4, "uaymjejb"
[#15945] DEBUG -- : [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [ae94a390-be07-4bdf-9fc5-dc7a58dd36ef] 
IndexMailer#send_reset_password_email: processed outbound mail in 153.7ms
[#15945]  INFO -- : [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [ae94a390-be07-4bdf-9fc5-dc7a58dd36ef] Performed ActionMailer::DeliveryJob from Inline(mailers) in 10221.58ms
[#15945] DEBUG -- :    (1.1ms)  ROLLBACK
[#15945]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10368ms (ActiveRecord: 7.6ms)
[#15945] FATAL -- : 
EOFError (end of file reached):
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:87:in `block in reset_password_transaction'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:85:in `reset_password_transaction'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:49:in `reset_password'
```

And this is the code block for the reset password:

```
# application_controller
def reset_password_transaction(user, password)
  user_params = { password: password, password_confirmation: password }
  user.transaction do
    if user.update user_params 
      IndexMailer.send_reset_password_email(user, password).deliver_later!
    else
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
    end
  end
end

# IndexMailer
def send_reset_password_email(user, password)
  return mail(
    to: user.email,
    subject: "Your password has been reset!",
    body: "Hey there!\n\n\n" +
          "You have recently asked to reset your password. Your temporary password is #{ password }.\n\n" +
          "You can reset your password through the settings once you login with your temporary password. Have a good day!")
end
```

Since this works in development, I can assume that there are no problems with the email content (e.g. malformed code) and that this must be a connection issue or something.

I am using Ruby v2.2.1p85 and Rails v4.2.5.2 if that helps. I have tried the following:

1. Clear cache: `rake tmp: clear`
2. Set authentication to `:plain`
3. Set `config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries` to true

Not sure what else I haven't tried. I would like to know why `EOFError` keeps happening ONLY in production.

Comment: What's on line 87 in `application_controller.rb / reset_password_transaction`?

Comment: Also since you say the only difference in production is username and password, how do you know the problem is not with those?

Comment: I updated the description to add the code for `reset_password_transaction`. I know that the problem is not in the credentials because if I use the prod credentials in development, the mailer still works. It's just in the production environment that it doesn't worl

Comment: I guess what I'm asking now is if there are additional logs I can look into aside from the Rails logs to debug the problem. The Rails logs aren't very helpful and I'm not familiar with what other logs I can check for this. I want to know if there is a problem connecting to google or something like that.